# mapStateToProps on functional component with PropTypes linting enabled

Tags: reactjs, redux, eslint, react-proptypes

We have a linting rule that makes React prop-types required.

Therefore, my file looks like this:

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2 }) => (
    <div>
        {*/ Do stuff here */}
    </div>
)

myComponent.propTypes = {
    prop1: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    prop2: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
}

export default MyComponent
```

And it is being used in a parent component like so:

```
<MyComponent prop1="Hello" prop2="World" />
```

Now, I want to connect this function component to Redux, so I now have this:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

...

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        prop3: state.area.prop3
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)
```

My problem is: when I attempt to add `prop3` like so:

```
const MyComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => {...}
```

My linter complains that:

```
'prop3' is missing in props validation eslint(react/prop-types)
```

Alright so I go to add it:

```
myComponent.propTypes = {
    prop1: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    prop2: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    prop3: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
}
```

But now, the parent component has an error:

```
Property 'prop3' is missing in type '{ prop1: any; prop2: any; }' but required in type 'Pick<Pick<Omit<{ prop1: any; prop2: any; prop3: any; }...
```

I suppose I could make `prop3` not required and include a `defaultProps` but that seems wrong to me since I am always going to grabbing it from state.

How do I connect to Redux state while also dealing with issues regarding PropTypes?

Edit: I'd rather not just disable the linting. Seems like a hack and there has to be a way to get this to work.

Comment: If you can, just use the Redux hooks. No connect, no props, no prop-types.
https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: I need `connect` because these are state data that I'm retrieving and mapping to `props` and I need to satisfy the `prop-types` linting somehow because that rule is enabled for our entire codebase.

Comment: @noblerare Did you try something like giving prop types to this `connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent)` instead of `MyComponent`? You can move the connect thing to a variable.

Comment: @noblerare I'm not sure I follow. You need access to these state data values within your component. It should not be necessary that they come in through the props. You can also get them with `useSelector`. `connect` by now is a legacy api when working with Redux and the hooks are officially recommended to access the store from function components. https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#use-the-react-redux-hooks-api